# Async AJAX call failing

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an async AJAX call using JQuery.

```
try
{
    let resp = await $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'https://xxxx/api/token',
        data: { AuthCode: authCode }
    });

    let accessToken = resp.access_token;
    document.getElementById("token").innerText = accessToken;

} catch (ex) {
    // Write the exception to the output area
    document.getElementById("token")
        .innerText = JSON.stringify(ex, null, 3);
}
```

For some reason this code is causing the following exception:

```
{
   "readyState": 4,
   "responseText": "{\"\":[\"The input was not valid.\"]}",
   "responseJSON": {
      "": [
         "The input was not valid."
      ]
   },
   "status": 400,
   "statusText": "Bad Request"
}
```

When I call the exact same API from Postman it returns a result with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably not POSTing to your endpoint with the right headers. Does your endpoint expect `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `application/json`? Either way, you can set the headers via the [headers](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) property like:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  headers: {
    "Content-Type":"application/json"
  }
});
```

Comment: agree with @Adam. I think Postman has any default headers but in jquery I hat to setup.

Comment: @Adam, yep, that did the trick. I can't believe I missed that.